# django tenant schema example gives ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: python, django

I installed django tenent schema app using pip. 
Then downloaded the tenant example app form "https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas/tree/master/examples/tenant_tutorial".
But when i try to run it I get following error 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: auth

Any idea why that may be happening?

python version 2.7
django version 1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

django-tenant-schemas has not been officially supported for Django version 1.7 (see https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas/pull/178).

I know this is not an answer to your question *"Any idea why that may be happening"*, but this at least explains why things don't work they way they should.

EDIT: As of django-tenant-schemas v1.5.1 (January 5th, 2015) Django 1.7 is supported.